# Execute an App registration without AzureAD

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

For a professional project, a chunk of the pipeline must be able to create an application (the first App registration, so I only have a global Admin) automatically within Azure AD. So far I used AzureAD which works well with Powershell 5.6 on Windows.
I now must be able to run the code with Ubuntu 20.04 and its Powershell 7.2. Unfortunately for me, AzureAD module is only supported on non-core Windows PowerShell, therefore it does not work on core PS6 or PS7. A very simplified piece of code is the following:

```
# Connection infos
$tenantId = "abcdef12345-1234-1234-124-abcdef12346789"
$account = "my_admin@domain.com" # Is cloud Admin by default
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($account, $password)

Connect-AzureAD -Credential $psCred -Tenant $tenantId

# Create app
$appName = "MyApp"

New-App -appName $appName -tenant_id $tenantId
```

I am stuck and my question is the following: how could I run such an operation with Powershell 7.2 considering AzureAD is not usable? I did check Connect-MgGraph for the connection part only (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell) but the clientId is an infos that I don't have -and want to create-.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use DeviceLogin as explained in this [article](https://blog.simonw.se/getting-an-access-token-for-azuread-using-powershell-and-device-login-flow/) to obtain an oAuth access token for you Global Administrator account in PowerShell (independent of the version) but this first step needs a human interaction.

After obtaining the token, you can use it to make Graph API calls with your Global Administrator permissions to [create an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Once you create your first application, you must attribute required permissions and use it to automate the process (obtain token programmatically using API calls) for application creation in PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks, but that part: "this first step needs a human interaction" is actually the part I want to automate...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC)](https://web.archive.org/web/20211027002122/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) to authenticate, however Microsoft actively discourages it in their documentation due to the security implications of sending a password over the wire.

If the security issues present with this method of authentication are still tolerated within your acceptance criteria, you would still need a ClientID. Luckily, [AzureAD has a well-known ClientID that you can use to authenticate](https://web.archive.org/web/20210410143214/https://www.vrdmn.com/2017/05/authenticating-to-microsoft-graph-api.html). This ID is `1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2`

The below Powershell code should get you started. I've basically translated the HTTP request within Microsoft's documentation into a [splatted](https://web.archive.org/web/20211118185106/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2) [Invoke-RestMethod](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2) command.

```
$LoginWithROPCParameters = @{
  URI = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token"
  Method = "POST"
  Body = @{
    client_id = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2"
    scope = "user.read openid profile offline_access"
    username = "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
    password = "hunter2"
    grant_type = "password"
  }
}
Invoke-RestMethod @LoginWithROPCParameters
```

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate on your solution, seems the way to do it!